# Multiple implode (PHP)

Tags: php, implode

I am attempting to create an [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) that given the following array:

```
<?php

    $conditions = array(
         'username' => array('=', 'nblackburn'),
         'password' => array('=', 'password')
    );

    $output = array();
    foreach($conditions as $key => $values) {
        $output[] = $key.' '.implode(' ', $values);
    }

    echo implode(' AND ', $output);

?>
```

Should return a string like the following:

```
username = nblackburn AND password = password
```

However, I am having problems getting it to work. As you can see the first section (`username`) is the array's key, the second (`=`) is the first element in the sub-array and the final (`nblackburn`) is its last element.

Comment: This sounds like you're preparing the array for using in SQL; make sure it's properly escaped and not vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: You would assume correctly there, the array key, condition and value would need escaping too.

Comment: This smells like reinvention of wheel. Why not use prepared statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
$str = array();
foreach($test as $key => $values) {

  // if there are always only 2 values inside
  $str[] = $key .' '.$values[0].' '.$values[1];

  // with more values (taken from nblackburns solution)
  $str[] = $key.' '.implode(' ', $values);
}

echo implode(' AND', $str);
```

But as mentioned in the comments, don't use it, if it brings vulnerabilities with it!

Comment: Kind of but there is no spacing and for some reason their seems to be a double "==" happening.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that too, are there always two values inside the array?

Comment: Managed to correct your code to what i need, thanks for the help, you have no idea how much it means to me :)